# Matching different labelling assign by KMeans

Tags: python, labeling

I have the following problem:

- I have two similar datasets composed of 3 columns of floats, normalized in the range [-1, 1]
- I can calculate the KMeans on each datasets with no problem

Now, given the similarity between the two datasets, I would like to "hack" them a bit and "match" the labeling between the clusters found by the algorithm.

For example:

1. in dataset **A**, I've found a cluster with the centroid at position **(1, 1)** and the algorithm assigned the label **0** to all the points in that cluster. There is another cluster in the dataset, this time identified by the centroid **(2, 2)** and the label **1**
2. in dataset **B**, I have similarly shaped clusters, however the label **0** is now associated to the cluster with the centroid **(1.4, 1.1)** while **1** is associated with the cluster at position **(2.1, 1.9)**

The variation is to underline the fact that centroid's positions among different cluster vary across the datasets.

I would like to find a way to relabel those segments in a way that in dataset B, all points that belong to the cluster with the centroid closer to the (1, 1) will have the same label (and the same for the other possible clusters as well).

Any ideas ?

Many thanks in advance, and forgive my english (not native speaker).

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use the mean of one of the features to get clusters labels.  We can force kmeans to produce the labels out of order by switching the order of the inputs.  In the second example I swapped the array positions, and increase feature1 by 10x.

We can use the mean of this feature along w/ `.rank()` in pandas to sort the issue out.  This could of course be more challenging if you have less clearly separated means, or if you have many features. In any case perhaps this could point you in the right direction.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['feature1','feature2'])
df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
df['rank'] = df.cluster.map(df.groupby('cluster')['feature1'].mean().rank()-1)
print(df)
```

In this output we see that the rank swaps the ordering of the clusters, due to cluster 1 having the smaller feature1 mean.

```
   feature1  feature2  cluster  rank
0         1         2        1   0.0
1         1         4        1   0.0
2         1         0        1   0.0
3        10         2        0   1.0
4        10         4        0   1.0
5        10         0        0   1.0
```

In the second example the smaller mean is already cluster zero so the rank matches the cluster.

```
X = np.array([[100, 2], [100, 4], [100, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]
              ])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['feature1','feature2'])
df2['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
df2['rank'] = df2.cluster.map(df2.groupby('cluster')['feature1'].mean().rank()-1)
print(df2)

   feature1  feature2  cluster  rank
0       100         2        1   1.0
1       100         4        1   1.0
2       100         0        1   1.0
3        10         2        0   0.0
4        10         4        0   0.0
5        10         0        0   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to compute dot product between centroids in each data set.
You can use an algorithm like the one below

```
for a in dsA.centroids:
   b = argmin(dot(a,dsB.centroids)
   # Relabel points in b to match label A
   dsB.centroids.remove(b)
```

You need to be careful while relabeling data points.  While doing that you need to be careful not to assign the label that belongs to a dataset you haven't relabeled yet.  There are multiple simple ways to avoid this clobbering.  The best way to do it depends on the exact data structures you use in your clustering algorithms